# Problems with Knockout mapping when using object inheritance

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Getting some weird behaviour I don't quite get when using the KO mapping plugin with subclassed objects.

Use case:

- The server has a number of simple model classes used for the AJAX
  API.
- I want to generate a stub class that generates KO observables 
  for properties on these classes, so that if I change the server code the 
  stub classes are automatically updated with an observable for the new
  property - I need this so I can create brand new objects without mapping from 
  existing data.
- I then want to be able to create a subclass of the stub that has e.g.
  computeds for the UI, action methods, client state etc. These additional
  properties do not need to be mapped back to the server - in fact they cannot
  be, as the server models will have them (or they'd be in the stub)

I am having problems getting this working.

Here is some cut down code:

```
function ItemModelBase(data, mapping)
{
    if(data)
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);

    this.Name = this.Name || ko.observable();
}

function ItemModel(data, mapping)
{
    var _this = this;

    ItemModelBase.call(this, data, mapping);

    this.Salutation = ko.computed(function() { return 'Hello ' + _this.Name(); });
}

// Comment this out and it works
ItemModel.prototype = new ItemModelBase;

function Model()
{
    var _this = this;

    var _mapping = {
        'Items': {
            create: function(o) { return new ItemModel(o.data); }
        }
    };

    this.Items = ko.observableArray();

    this.load = function()
    {
        ko.mapping.fromJS({ 
            Items: [
                { Name: 'Aardvark' },
                { Name: 'Bat' },
                { Name: 'Cheetah' },
                { Name: 'Duiker' },
                { Name: 'Ocelot' }
            ]
        }, _mapping, _this);                          
    };
}

var model = new Model();
ko.applyBindings(model);
model.load();
```

Using view:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: Items">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>: 
        <span data-bind="text: Salutation"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What this displays is a list of the correct number of items, but only using data from the last item - result:

- Ocelot: Hello Ocelot
- Ocelot: Hello Ocelot
- Ocelot: Hello Ocelot
- Ocelot: Hello Ocelot
- Ocelot: Hello Ocelot

If I don't subclass the base object, i.e. I comment out the `ItemModel.prototype = new ItemModelBase;` line, it works as expected.

My main language is C# and I find Javascript's inheritance very difficult to get my head round; what is going on here? As far as I can tell, without the prototype it works because the base constructor call is just A.N. Other JS call that is adding a load of properties to the current instance.

This works for this case, but presumably means if I add some common functions to the base class prototype I won't be able to use them?

I guess I need a main single question, so it is: Why is only the last item being displayed, and what do I do about it?

JFfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/whelkaholism/d427mssa/

EDIT: If I include the inheritance and then create a new model, that new model has the properties of the last item too. REALLY don't understand that, but it looks like it's assigning values to the prototype not the instance?

```
console.log(ko.toJSON(new ItemModel()));
```

Results in:

```
{"Name":"Ocelot","Salutation":"Hello Ocelot"}
```

EDIT: [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak) posted an answer which seems to have been deleted, which is a shame as although I still don't know what is going on, it did actually give a fix.

The problem is this: `this.Name = this.Name || ko.observable();`

If I move the observable definition above the mapping it works:

```
function ItemModelBase(data, mapping)
{
    this.Name = ko.observable();
    // Exhibits the same bug as original code
    // this.Name = this.Name || ko.observable();

    if(data)
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);       
}
```

Oddly leaving the condition it results in the same bug, even though my understanding of JS was that this.Name would be undefined at that point, resulting that statement having the value of `ko.observable()' and being identical to the code without the cnodition?

Comment: Look at the constructor chaining example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: I'm not seeing the relevance of that example I'm afraid? The issue is not being able to chain constructors per se, it is the prototype inheritance and the specific problem it causes with Knockout mapping.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're hoping to get from having a prototype. Typically, a prototype contains (only) methods. You've made it contain Name, a property, which means there is one Name shared by all instances that don't have their own Name property.

Comment: This is a cut down example; there is no point admittedly in assigning the prototype here, but in real code I might want to add utility methods.

However, I think you've identified my problem actually; I was thinking in C# terms of property accessors being overridable, but if setting the prototype results in sharing of actual property values, then that is definitely not what I want - I should be thinking of them being more like C# fields, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't attempt to create computeds or observables anywhere up the prototype chain. Here's what you can and can't do:

- You can modify the prototype to share share common, non-observable (!) properties and methods between viewmodels.

  ```
  var common = {
      baz: function () {
          return ko.unwrap(this.bar) || ko.unwrap(this.foo);
      }
  };

  function VM1() {
      this.foo = ko.observable();
  }
  VM1.prototype = common;

  function VM2() {
      this.foo = ko.observable();
      this.bar = ko.observable();
  }
  VM2.prototype = common;

  var vm2 = new VM2();
  vm2.foo("FOO");
  vm2.baz();  // -> returns "FOO";
  ```
- You can't (read: shouldn't) have other viewmodels in the prototype chain. Since all prototypes are living object instances themselves, all their observables would be shared between your *actual* viewmodel instances. The only situation where doing this would make sense is if you wanted to share subscribable (!) data between instances.

  ```
  function VM0() {
      this.count = ko.observable(0);
  }
  VM0.prototype.increment = function () {
      this.count(this.count() + 1);
  };

  function VM1() {
      this.foo = ko.observable();
      this.count.subscribe(function (newCount) {
          // count has increased across all VM1 instances
      });
  }
  VM1.prototype = new VM0();

  var vm1 = new VM1();
  vm1.inc();  // -> triggers subscription across all VM1 instances
  ```
- You can use functions to attach common, self-contained functionality (including observables) to a viewmodel instance. That's basically what applying a different constructor like `ItemModelBase.call(this, ...);` would do.

  ```
  function VM1() {
      this.foo = ko.observable();
  }

  function VM2() {
      VM1.call(this);   // creates foo observable
      this.bar = ko.observable();
  }
  ```
- You cannot call `ko.mapping` more than once on the same viewmodel instance (i.e. first map basic properties, then specific ones). The mapping plugin keeps its internal state in an instance variable itself - a second run would overwrite the state of the first. (Of course you can still map *the same* list of properties a second time, i.e. update their values.)

All of this leaves you with pretty little room for a C# type inheritance hierarchy. Unless you have common functionality to share, don't bother building a viewmodel hierarchy in JS.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks, particularly the bit at the end about the ko.mapping.

I don't need a deep inheritance hierarchy; what I am trying to do is to have the server side code, which has simple model objects, generate KO stubs for these. This means that if I add a new property to the server object I automatically get an observable added to the stub (this is required for creating brand new objects that are not mapped from existing data). I will then create a single extra subclass level that has, e.g.  computeds for the UI, observables for state etc. These will not need to be ... 1/2

Comment: 2/2 ... mapped to and from the server so your restriction is not a problem.

Comment: I will clarify the question with more info about the actual use case, but both answers I have so far are very helpful.

Comment: I think you really need to sit down first and read up on how prototype inheritance works. :) A property on the prototype is not *actually* inherited to an different object further down the chain. Instead, If an object down the chain is asked for a property, JS walks up the chain until it finds an object that has the property. Don't think in classes, there are no classes in JS. There only are objects. The prototype chain is a singly linked list beween actual object instances.

Comment: Yeah, I'm reading up but it seem to not be something my brain is easily able to click with. I think the advice to let go of classes is good. TBH I think I have a reasonable intuition of how it actually works now, it's just I thought maybe I was doing something wrong because it's so different to the class based systems I'm more used to.

Comment: You really need to let go of the notion of class-based abstraction, it won't do you any favors. It fosters over-engineering and leads to shoehorning the language into concepts it wasn't built around. For example, there aren't any *actual* constructors in JS. There are constructor functions, whose job it is to augment plain, empty objects with a defined set of properties. Prototypes merely exist to avoid having to create 1000 copies of the same method for 1000 object instances.

Comment: 'kay, I have accepted your very in-depth assisatmce, thanks!

Comment: @Whelkaholism Uhhh, no you didn't. ;)

Comment: @Whelkaholism So, out of interest, did you manage to solve it to your satisfaction?

Comment: Yes; what I actually wanted was the "common, self-contained functionality" from your answer, so I went with that; a simple "stub" object that the server generated with all the basic observables on it, then my actual viewmodels called the constructor of that to apply all of those before adding more complicated logic. It keeps everything neat and means I don't have to make any manual changes if the models the server expects add/remove any of the simple properties.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is your test for whether a Name property exists. Because it exists in the prototype, it exists. If you use

```
if (!this.hasOwnProperty('Name')) { this.Name = ko.observable(); }
```

for your test-and-assign, it should do what you expect.

Comment: A light bulb is beginning to glow dimly over my head. I think I might be having an XY Problem moment; thanks for this.